# Framework CSS "windows 95" like

Tags: css, windows

We have a client that build his mockups under visual studio, and he wants that the web application looks like the same as his windows application.

My eyes are constantly bleeding when I see those mockups but, **any chance someone crazy enough created a Css framework that look like windows form & buttons** ?

Thanks

[image: Beware your eyes may bleed]

Comment: Did you ever find something? I am on EXACTLY the same situation.

Comment: No, we went with bootsrap with ugly modification. good luck though. I feel your pain from here. See https://github.com/kristopolous/BOOTSTRA.386

Comment: have a look over here: http://inscenedev.noip.me/stuff/webdesign/win95/

Answer (score 3):

Here is an emulated [Win95 Desktop](http://websitesthatmarket.com/win95/) made with CSS. That might help.

Comment: LOL, in fact my question is serious, i don't know why i get all the vote down. Anyway, i'm not looking for the desktop, but only form elements.

Comment: @Tristan, Your question is getting downvoted and closed. All because this is way to localized to you, and not community friendly.

Comment: @Starx I'd say this is just off-topic. Should be moved to webmasters or webapps maybe. Could be a great question there or on a design stackexchange site if there is any :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa, Yeah but localized too

Comment: All because this is way to localized to you. I disagree, i think of all web designers who'll have clients that want to stick to their "feel windows 95" touch.

Comment: @Tristan, I should have raised another question? Have you started doing anything on this? got stuck some where? searched some where? I pasted that link after a plain google search.

Comment: Ofc I searched. Your answer does not answer my question I'm looking a css framework for the form element. You gave the Desktop of windows 95 made in css... completely different. Plus i wanted to know if there are such thing before start doing something about it.

Comment: To answer my own question : https://github.com/kristopolous/BOOTSTRA.386